# More formal way of saying "taking almost all"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, academia, academic-writing

I am trying to revise the following statement:

> A takes almost all the rewards which are usually given to clients contributing important attributes.

The `takes almost all` seems not very formal and concise to me. Is there any other `verb` that can be properly used here?

> A [verb] rewards which are usually given to clients contributing important attributes.

Thank you!

Comment: "The vast majority" is a more formal way of saying "almost all". I don't believe you will find a verb that means "takes almost all", certainly not a formal one.

Comment: I'd go with *hogs* or *hoards* the rewards.

Comment: The verb _monopolise_ can certainly mean 'take the greatest share of', but 'monopolised the awards/prizes' are unidiomatic.

Comment: I think it is worth saying that what I shall call 'public' or 'official' writing has been relaxing its preference for formality for quite some time.  There are many reasons for this, but in essence it follows from the way in which the social and educational backgrounds included in the intended audience for written English has steadily broadened over the years.  So there is less and less between outright slang and so-called 'formal' communication.  So what exactly is it about "takes almost all" that bothers you?  You could replace "takes" with "grabs" or a synonym of that to make it stronger.

Comment: It is not a good idea to think that more complicated sounding writing means better writing.

Answer (score 1):

A takes the lion's share.

> In English the phrase used in the sense of nearly all only appeared at the end of
> the 18th century;[2]
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion%27s_share

Answer (score 0):

This statement is probably meant to compliment A, to show that A ticks almost all the boxes. I think "almost all" can sound alright with a good verb. I would say:

> A ***reaps*** almost all the rewards which are usually given to clients contributing important attributes.

I also like ***earn***, and if you want to replace ***almost all*** at all costs, you could say

> A  ***earns most of*** the rewards which are usually given to clients contributing important attributes.

Comment: Perhaps "garners" in place of "earns"?